# Javascript timestamp limit to the last 8 characters

Tags: javascript

It is simple enough to get timestamp:

```
new Date().getTime();
```

but I need to limit the timestamp to 8 characters, and these need to be the last 8 rather than the first 8.

for example:

```
new Date().getTime(); // returns: 1234567891234
```

I need it to return:

```
67891234
```

can you help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Convert to string -> substring.

Comment: @Felix Kling - isn't modulus(%) simpler?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
new Date().getTime().toString().substr(-8);
```

Comment: You can't use negative lengths in [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring).

Comment: Yes you can. Try it into jsfiddle or your browser's console.

Comment: @Florent: No you can't: http://jsfiddle.net/ShF52/  From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring): "An integer between 0 and..."

Comment: @Florent:... Goddammit JavaScript.  I didn't realize there was `substr` and `substring` =/  Sorry :-P

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
var last8numbers = String(new Date().getTime()).substr(-8);
```

From [Mozilla's `substr` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr):

> If start is negative, substr uses it as a character index from the end of the string.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `%` (modulus) to get the value you want. You don't need to convert the value to string at all.

```
var x = new Date().getTime(); 
var y = x%100000000;
```

This code prints  1234567891234 & 67891234

```
var x = 1234567891234;
var y = x%100000000;
alert(x + " & " + y);​
```

Comment: @Rocket if it doesn't then what I learnt in college is wrong. :-)

Comment: This is a great answer if you want to end up with an integer. Just depends on what data type you need. This is going to be better performance (I imagine) if you need a number.

Comment: I must admit if I saw this in code I'd think wtf. Not very obvious as to what its doing...

Comment: @Chris Moutray - that is why comments are for.

Answer (score 2):

Given:

```
var foo = 1234567891234;
foo.toString().substring(foo.length - 8, foo.length); // returns 67891234
```